# Science fiction novel where Earth is invaded by aliens landing at the North Pole

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for an old sci-fi book which I read about 13-15 years ago. Unfortunately there isn't much I recall, only few bits and pieces from the first book:

The story is about Earth being invaded by aliens. An empty ship approaches Earch (similar to RAMA), lands on the North pole, and later aliens start to pour out  of it  (ship seems to be serving as some kind of "Ark" for teleportation) attacking Earth.

The name of the main character - female, sergeant in the military, is "Four", or at least I recall it as being translated into my language as "Four" (Четири).

Sadly, that's about all I recall from the book. Been searching for awhile trying to  find it and/or remember more so I can re-read it but so far my search has been futile.

Does this ring any bell to anyone?

Comment: You'd think that Santa's elves would take care of them in fairly short order.

Comment: Do you know that it was translated from English? There's a French book called 'les visiteurs du pole nord' or 'visitors from the north pole' that could be similar.

Comment: I can only speculate, if the translation was from english. But I think I recall the book (at least the first one) actually being named after the main character. I'll check that french book though.

Comment: Doesnt' seems to be 'les visiteurs du pole nord' or 'visitors from the north pole' . Thanks for trying though :)

Comment: I haven't read the book in ages, but a base at the North Pole is I think a feature of Harry Harrison's "Invasion:Earth!". Mind you, there are two alien races in that book.